# Play array of sounds without deleay

Tags: javascript, delay, html5-audio

I have created an array of Audio each audio is a String of the path of the .wav file.  I am trying to play the sounds but I hear a short delay between each file played.
Here is my code:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
      var sounds = [];
      var i = -1;
      /*<![CDATA[*/
            /*[# th:each="chord : ${chords}"]*/
                sounds.push(new Audio(/*[[${chord.audio}]]*/))
            /*[/]*/
        /*]]>*/
      function playSnd() {
          i++;
          if (i == sounds.length) {
            i = -1;
            return;
          }
          sounds[i].addEventListener('ended', playSnd);
          sounds[i].play();
      }
      function addSound(clicked_id) {
          sounds.push(new Audio(clicked_id));
      }
 </script>
```

My question: is there a better way to handle audio files and removing that few ms of delay between each audio?

Comment: wav files are huge compared to mp3 -- like up to 10 times larger. Download [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) and convert your wav files into mp3.

Answer (score 0):

Along with converting to mp3 you could also preload the audio files and only play them once they are all load. The oncanplaythrough method could help with this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oncanplaythrough

Answer (score 0):

Like Zer00ne said, convert wav to mp3 to make the file smaller.

However, if that cannot be done, you can also use the method timeupdate(e). It will continuously fire upon playing. Start the next track a second before it finishes:

*Disclaimer: Haven't tested the code below.*

```js
sounds[i].addEventListener('timeupdate', (e) => {
  if (!e.target.nextTrackStarted) {
    if ((e.target.duration - e.target.currentTime) < 2) {
      e.target.nextTrackStarted = true;
      playSnd();
    }
  }
});
```